# Is there a way to access the media picker without using @Model in Umbraco 7.6.3

Tags: model, umbraco, media, picker

I've taken over management for a website built in Umbraco 7.6.3 and the company that built the system has utilized a traditional .Net MVC. Which means that much of the functionality native to Umbraco is lost.

I need to be able to render images selected using the Media.Picker however the only place that I can find any documentation on accessing that object all require that I use the `@Model` in umbraco in order to resolve the Url of the selected image.

If I attempt to use the standard Umbraco Model by inheriting

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage
```

I get the following error: because the company who integrated this system went far outside of Umbraco best practices and built their own model for all pages within the site...

> Cannot bind source type
>   ClassName.Web.ViewModels.Templates.HomeViewModel to model type
>   Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent.

I'm building the needed section of the pages using a Partial View

Any suggestions would be very very useful to me??!!!

In the below code - the `@ogimageId.ToString()` returns the following

```
[ Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.PublishedMediaCache+DictionaryPublishedContent ]
```

and I can't figure out how to either get the url directly from this object, nor it's ID so that I can use the method below it to get the url from the id of the image...

```
@using Umbraco.Web;
@using Umbraco.Web.Extensions;
@using ClientDependency.Core.Mvc;
@{
    dynamic ogimageId = Umbraco.Field("ogimage", recursive: true);
    <!-- ogimageUrl: @ogimageId.ToString() -->
    string ogimage = Umbraco.Media(1143).umbracoFile.ToString();
}
<meta property="og:image" content="@ogimage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out before anyone had a chance to respond... 
Here's the solution... didn't realize it would be so simple...
Html.Raw converts the id for you.

`string ogimageId = Html.Raw(Umbraco.Field("ogimage", recursive: true)).ToString();
    string ogimage = Umbraco.Media(ogimageId).umbracoFile.ToString();`

Comment: Take a look at my comment on the other answer - this is slightly better, however using `UmbracoHelper` is the generally accepted way to go.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `MediaService` for accessing the media.

```
@ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService.GetById(1143).GetValue<string>("umbracoFile")
```

Then extract the url from that json string.

```
dynamic media = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService.GetById(1068).GetValue<string>("umbracoFile"));
```

Finally, `@media.src` will give you the url.

Comment: A better way is to use the UmbracoHelper - however you may have to create an instance if you aren't using an `UmbracoSurfaceController` or the `UmbracoViewPage`: `var Umbraco = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);` Then you can use `Umbraco.TypedMedia` etc.